# Administrative Levels of countries as polygons

Tags: asp.net, maps, gis, openstreetmap, geonames

I am trying to create a database (SQL Server) with countries and administrative levels through out the world, especially Europe.

I want to use polygon data for all the areas, and use search and get "point in polygon" results.

I've looked at different places for data, but I find it kind of difficult to extract the correct data, and use it.
My problem is I really don't know where to start.

I've looked at geonames, google maps and openstreetmap for data, and I think OSM is the best. But I don't know how to extract it.

How to extract polygon data from OSM, or another great solution.

Comment: Did you ever figure out a good solution?  I'm dealing with the same issue.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [GADM](http://www.gadm.org), where you will find shapefiles (also kml, etc) for every country. Unfortunately, the admin areas are not always up-to-date, so if accuracy is vital. you will need to do some work to improve them. I also suspect (comparing GADM's UK shapes with those from the Ordnance Survey) that a certain amount of simplification has taken place, leading to 'point in polygon' errors, especially at country boundaries.

I agree that OSM is better than most, but the extraction of polygons from the OSM data has not been as straightforward as I would have hoped.

Comment: Hi Robert, thanks for your answer.
My look at gadm starter with admiration, but I was quite disappointed. The admin boundaries where wrong, for the first country I tried to use data for, and I need some more levels of administration. OSM has all of this... But I can't figure out how to extract it.

Maybe import it to some GIS software, and create it from there and export?